# Sharing DNA record between two ancestry accounts

Tags: dna, united-kingdom, australia

My DNA record is in my Australian account and I have activated a UK ancestry account, how do I get the UK account to recognise the DNA record in my Australian account.

The reason I did this is because I have no Australian ancestry.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to simply log into Ancestry UK using your Australian account login (same email and password), and be able to access the DNA results there. You can access any Ancestry site using a single account.

One other option is to share your DNA results with the UK account, but the Australian account will remain the primary account for the DNA test. For details on how to do this see [Sharing AncestryDNA Results](https://support.ancestry.co.uk/s/article/Sharing-AncestryDNA-Results).